# Error inflating Map fragment when run release

Tags: android

I read many similar topics, and tried all accepted answer but nothing worked.
My app works fine when I run as debug, but when I generated .apk file, install it on my phone, it crashed.

I got that error

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vn.com.ttsoft.dhd/vn.com.ttsoft.dhd.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

The error caused by line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);`

I added this to my Manifest, as someone said in another question. But it doesn't work.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

My activity extends FragmentActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Here's my activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="vn.com.ttsoft.dhd.MapsActivity" />
```

My phone runs android 7.1 Nougat. Anyone knows the solution, please?

Comment: Have you enabled pro guard?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker#manifest

Comment: @user1209216 I set "minifyEnabled" to false.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya nothing different if I add "<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" or not.

Comment: Could you share the part of your program where you are inflating your xml?

Comment: Try to Invalidate Cache & Restart option, then rebuild your apk

Comment: @ScottS I updated it above.

Answer (score 0):

I update classpath to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` and it worked! Previous version is 2.3.3.

Now I get error when "Rebuild the project", but when I "Generate signed APK" and install this .apk file on my phone, it works fine. How strange it is!